# How to find the lowest whole divisor of a number?

Tags: divisibility

How do I find the lowest divisor of a number so that if we divide the number by the divisor we will get a whole number?

I need a basic formula.  (This is for coding.)

Answer (score 1):

That will be the smallest prime dividing the number. There is no formula for that.

Comment: that is, you have to divide your number by 2, 3, 5, 7, ... until you stumble into an integer result

Answer (score 1):

You have to test division with all primes up to $ \sqrt x $.